# How can i do to interact with web3 on the server side?

Tags: web3js, transactions, wallets

I'm trying to develop a web application that interacts with web3.
I have to create accounts, wallet and perform transaction.
I'd like to know which is the best way to interact with web3 on the server side.

Comment: Just require the library in your nodejs code.
What are you writing your server in?

Comment: PHP, i'm not be able to integrate php with nodejs

Comment: You need a library that implements this https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Comment: Or you could write your own library that sends requests to an Ethereum node

Comment: Write node scripts that PHP calls to execute. Or as already stated, create your own PHP library or find someone that has. :)

Comment: I've added an answer that states this

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you're using PHP on the server side, check out the **[ethereum-php](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php)** client.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ethereum\Ethereum;

try {
    $eth = new Ethereum('https://mainnet.infura.io');
    echo $eth->eth_protocolVersion()->val();
}
catch (\Exception $exception) {
    die ("Unable to connect.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the Ethereum network you need to be able to communicate with a node.

The `web3` library does exactly this but it is for JavaScript. For other languages you need to find a library that has the [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) calls implemented or write your own library that does this.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, we have another native golang binding with smart contract, we dont need to use web3

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts